# Confused about behavior of OPTIONAL MATCH clause

Tags: neo4j

Running this under Neo4j 2.0.

I've designed a Node type system using an array property called "type".  This was done prior to labels and I'll probably switch to using labels eventually. For now, I have the following delete query:

```
START n = node(*) OPTIONAL MATCH n-[r]-() WHERE ANY(x in n.type WHERE x = 'TestType') DELETE n, r
```

Note that prior to Neo4j 2.0, I used the following query which worked fine:

```
START n = node(*) MATCH n-[r?]-() WHERE ANY(x in n.type WHERE x = 'TestType') DELETE n, r
```

The intent is to delete all Nodes with the type 'TestType'.  (The OPTIONAL MATCH clause is there to delete any relationships that may exist so the nodes can be deleted.) However, this results in deleting Nodes of other types as well.  If I remove the OPTIONAL MATCH clause (and assuming the Nodes have no relationships), this works as expected and only nodes of type 'TestType' are deleted.

In trying to debug this, I changed the DELETE to RETURN and saw that with the OPTIONAL MATCH clause, nodes of all types were returned.  When I removed the OPTIONAL MATCH clause, only nodes of type 'TestType' were returned.

Is this a bug or am I not using OPTIONAL MATCH correctly?

Thanks.

Addendum:

The query suggested by Dan G produced the same incorrect results.  All nodes were found rather than just the nodes with the given type.  However the following query worked although I don't quite understand why I needed to do this:

```
START n=node(*)
WHERE 'TestType' IN n.`Node-typenames`
WITH n
OPTIONAL MATCH n-[r]-() DELETE n,r
```

Could someone help me better understand this?

Comment: Updated post with additional information

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work:

```
Match (n)
optional match (n)-[r]->()
where 'TestType' in n.type
delete n,r
```

Comment: I'll try it.  But that doesn't explain why my original query doesn't work and why it's affected by the OPTIONAL MATCH clause.